# Accessing onClick fn of a nested button in Enzyme & React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Essentially, I'm trying to test if my modal opens when my button is clicked & I'm a noob with Jest & Enzyme.

I am hitting an issue accessing the props on the button & I'm not sure if it's because it's nested inside of a third party package or if I'm not importing it correctly into my test. Please see my condensed(ish) code below as I wasn't about to recreate the code on CodePen..

**DataTable.jsx**

```
const UploadDownloadComponent = ({ handleOpen }) => (
  <UploadDownloadButtonContainer>
    <PrimaryButton
      id="bulk-add-button"
      onClick={handleOpen} //this is what I need to access
    >
      Bulk Add Members
    </PrimaryButton>
    <SecondaryButton id="email-csv-button">
    </SecondaryButton>
  </UploadDownloadButtonContainer>
);

//beginning of data table component
export const Table = () => {
  const [bulkUpload, setBulkUpload] = useState(false);

  //upload modal
  const openUpload = () => {
    setBulkUpload(true);
  };
  const closeUpload = () => {
    setBulkUpload(false);
  };

  //query container
  const subHeaderComponentMemo = useMemo(() => {
    {*/ other code /*}

    return (
      <div>
        <UploadDownloadComponent
          handleOpen={openUpload}
          bulkUpload={bulkUpload}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }, []);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DataTable
        {*/ bunch of other things unrelated /*}
        subHeaderComponent={subHeaderComponentMemo}
      />
      <UploadModal closeModal={closeUpload} open={bulkUpload} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

**DataTable.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { configure, mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { Table } from "../components/MemberView/DataTable";
import { UploadModal } from "../components/MemberView/UploadModal";
import Modal from "react-modal";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<Table />", () => {

  const wrapper = mount(<Table />);

  //using .upDate() is the only way I can get this test to pass
  it("should have upload button", () => {
    const uploadButton = wrapper.find("#bulk-add-button").update();
    expect(uploadButton).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  //this passes
  it("renders Upload Modal", () => {
    const upModal = shallow(<UploadModal />);
    expect(upModal.find(Modal)).toHaveLength(1);
  });


  it("opens Upload Modal when state is changed", () => {
    const modal = mount(<UploadModal />);

    expect(modal.find(Modal).prop("isOpen")).toBe(false);

    const uploadButton = wrapper.find("#bulk-add-button").update();
    expect(uploadButton.length).toEqual(1);

    //this is where my test fails as it cannot simulate click on uploadButton
    uploadButton.simulate("click");

    //if I change it to: 
    wrapper.find("#bulk-add-button").simulate("click')
    //my error message says it expected 1 Node. ) found instead.

    //I don't make it this far
    expect(modal.find(Modal).prop("isOpen")).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I am also using Hooks if that makes any difference...

Any and all help/advice welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When accessing props the following approach works for me.

```
expect(modal.find(Modal).props().isOpen).toBe(false);
```

Hope this works!